# How do I self close vote on my own question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

My [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/108593/94977) is no longer in the scope since the service has become obsolete. So, I just found that someone has already voted to close the question as off-topic with good reason:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can no longer be reproduced. The encrypted.google.com site no longer exists. – forest [20 mins ago](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108593/unable-to-access-encrypted-google-com-with-proxy-googlezip-net?noredirect=1#comment417058_108593)

Now, I agree with the reason and want to vote for closing on that reason but I am not finding a way to do this. I'm not having `close` button yet and `flag` button doesn't include that feature I think. Also there is no button like "That's solved my problem" as we find in the case of closing as duplicate:

[image]

So-that community user can close the question automatically.

Now, how do I approach for self-closing my own question? Should I consider to use custom flag for mods?

Answer (score 5):

Once you have 250 rep you will be able to do this. From the privileges page:

> View Close Votes
> Privilege Type: Moderation Privilege
>
> Awarded At: 250 Reputation
>
> This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions

Answer (score 3):

[As stated by Rory Alsop](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3184/59741), users with 250 rep can vote to close your own question. Note that even if users self-vote their questions to be closed, it will be just another vote; [*it still won't be binding*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-askers-to-close-their-own-questions-unilaterally). (Only duplicate votes by gold badgers and all votes by mods are binding)

However, the alternative option is to delete your question as a courtesy for cleaning up, especially since it doesn't have any answers yet and obsolete/unanswerable at the same time.